# How to pass secrets using vault into docker container?

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, hashicorp-vault

In past, I used to store all my secrets (i.e. DB connection, API keys and SSH certificates) into either .env file or a secret file (in most of my projects) of Docker. Now, I know Vault as a tool to store all credentials and access through API calls. However, my biggest question on how to pass docker environment variables in a docker container that I store into the vault remains unanswered. I researched quite a lot, but I didn't get any proper solution. That would be great to see some concrete examples if you guys may know any.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of the workflow you're thinking of?

Comment: Do you want to insert dynamically secrets into docker while starting your container?

Comment: @samthegolden I want to try both dynamically and static secrets while starting the container.